# 1.5 TB USB Drive failed to mount

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, usb-drive, fat32

Seagate 1.5Tb FreeAgent USB Hard Drive. Formatted FAT32. I figure it is 75% full.
Used to work fine in XUBUNTU it shows up in Cairo Dock but when I click on it I get "failed to mount drive'. Nautilus does not display the icon nor does Thunar.
Windows Vista will no longer recognise drive either.
Back Track 5R3 also no longer fails to mount it.
BUT and here is the BIG BUT my Pioneer DV-410 reads the files and plays the everything just fine.

I believe this all happened after an unclean shutdown / XUbuntu 12.10 system freeze. Why can't XUBUNTU mount this drive when a crappy 13 year old DVD player can mount it. I am desperate to back up the data before just in case the drive becomes completely unreadable.

Using XUBUNTU 12.10 Quantal current 3.5.0.17 Kernel (past 3 Kernels wont read it either) and all newest apt-get update / dist-upgrade are applied. I will post any other info you folks request as needed.

---

Additional info as requested by githlar.

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdb
dosfsck 3.0.13, 30 Jun 2012, FAT32, LFN
Read 512 bytes at 0:Input/output error

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:3001 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: First off, try doing a filesystem check on it. The command to do this is fsck.vfat /dev/sdb1 (You find the actual device (may not be sdb1) for the partition by checking it out in gparted). Also, an `lsusb` would be handy (make sure the drive is plugged in when you do this).

Answer (score 0):

If the **partition table** is messed up you can try to repair it with [**TestDisk**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).
You can install it in ubuntu from `apt-get` and use it on the HDD in question. The process to **repair filesystem** is reasonably straight forward and automatic if you follow the prompts. You can look [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery) for a **tutorial** into its usage.